# How to write (number of notifications) in the address bar when a notification is found

Tags: html, notifications, titlebar

Does any of you know how most of the websites today show the number of notifications in the title bar when a new notification is found? Like if you have a notification on Facebook you get (1) Facebook in the title bar. How could I do that?

Comment: do you mean title bar? changing the address bar changes what page you are on...

Comment: How can I detect the number of notifications? I'm using jquery to refresh the notifications area by loading another php page in a div. So how can I use javascript to detect the number of notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses simple Javascript. First, the title of the document is stored somewhere so when the title is written to multiple times, it doesn't prepend multiple `(1)`s to the title (i.e., you wouldn't want `(3) (1) Facebook`). Then it sets `document.title` to that original title while putting some bit of information on the front, something like this:

```
original_title = document.title

// time passes

document.title = "(" + update_count + ") " + original_title;
```

Comment: How can I detect the number of notifications? I'm using jquery to refresh the notifications area by loading another php page in a div. So how can I use javascript to detect the number of notifications?

Comment: to people who trying to do this with jquery ajax request: just put orginal_title out of document ready and put other line to inside ajax success part.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the **title** bar by setting it explicitly:

```
document.title = document.title + ' (' + notificationCount+ ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the title bar, then you can use JavaScript:

```
var notifications = 2;
document.title = "("+ notifications +") ...";
```